# recover_key in contract

Tags: smart-contract

Is there a specific sample code of using recover_key()? I got an error with recover_key() in contract.

```
string msg="charlie";
checksum256 m_hash;
sha256( const_cast<char*>(msg.c_str()), msg.length(), &m_hash );
char* pub;
string sig="SIG_K1_K5cpBg7XHRfgdedEAR9w74bXQZk4TUQk9QDMfzNbttY3eZ5WhmpNuWKiRyidskkdjBH9L9pKKe29RiiELNLCNYzFtFyTqJ";
recover_key(&m_hash,sig.data(),strlen(maker.sig.data()),pub,sizeof(char));
```

Error Information:

```
assert_exception: Assert Exception
w < count():
{}
thread-0  static_variant.hpp:339 set_which
Error unpacking field _storage
{"field":"_storage"}
thread-0  raw.hpp:368 operator()
error unpacking fc::crypto::signature
{"type":"fc::crypto::signature"}
thread-0  raw.hpp:616 unpack
```

Comment: Can u give me a example about how you call ecverify action by cleos? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/crypto.h>
using namespace eosio;

class ec: public eosio::contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

  ///@abi action
  void ecverify(std::string data, const signature &sig, const public_key &pk)
  {
    checksum256 digest;
    sha256(&data[0], data.size(), &digest);

    assert_recover_key(&digest, (const char *)&sig, sizeof(sig), (const char *)&pk, sizeof(pk));
    print("VALID");
  }
};

EOSIO_ABI( ec, (ecverify) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void assert_recover_key2(const checksum256* digest, const signature* sig, const eosio::public_key* pub) {
     public_key pub2;
     pub2.data[0] = char(pub->type.value);
     memcpy(&pub2.data[1], pub->data.data(), 33);
     assert_recover_key(digest, (const char*)sig, sizeof(signature), (const char*)&pub2, sizeof(public_key));
```

}

that's my code, take care the public_key and eosio::public_key is not same

Comment: what's the format of sig? my signature is string like "SIG_K1_K5cpBg7XHRfgdedEAR9w74bXQZk4TUQk9QDMfzNbttY3eZ5WhmpNuWKiRyidskkdjBH9L9pKKe29RiiELNLCNYzFtFyTqJ",How to converto to signature type?

Comment: @BruceLingKing just pass the string in your action, and eos will convert it to eosio::public_key directly

Comment: I did it as u said .But when send action,the errors occured "Error: Non-base58 character order.sig = "SIG_K1_K5cpBg7XHRfgdedEAR9w74bXQZk4TUQk9QDMfzNbttY3eZ5WhmpNuWKiRyidskkdjBH9L9pKKe29RiiELNLCNYzFtFyTqJ""

Comment: According to my test, assert_recover_key2 would failed!When I modify it as bellow,it success.   assert_recover_key(digest, (const char*)sig, sizeof(signature), (const char*)&(pub2.data), sizeof(public_key));

Comment: @BruceLingKing any difference with &pub2.data and &pub2?

Comment: I don't know the reason.use &pub2 just failed.

Comment: @BruceLingKing I know, you use eosio::public_key instead of public_key, and luckily, you changed the data from 33 chars to 34 chars, but that may cause overflow

Comment: Hi,@Jimmy Guo .Another problem is how to know whether a public key is belong to an account in contract.I think this is very important when we wanna check the signature of an account

Comment: @BruceLingKing no, you don't need, because it has been done by eos node, just use require_auth