# Check public keys on contract level

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, eosio.cdt, account-name, public-key

Is it meanwhile possible to check the public key of an account name on contract level? (Not with Cleos)

Example: The contract contains some public keys (not the account names).
If a user performs a function in the contract, the contract should check if the user name belongs to one of the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is by using *recover_key()*, *assert_recover_key()* or *assert_recover_key2()* while passing an additional signature and digest to the action, as described here:

[recover_key in contract](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/recover-key-in-contract/2986)